# Subscription - How to update the next billing date with Braintree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree, recurring-billing

When creating a new subscription, the `next_billing_date` was successfully saved into the database. However, how do I update the `next_billing_date` in my database every time when a new recurring charge occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Subscription webhooks](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/webhooks/subscription/ruby). When Braintree fires a webhook, it will include a subscription response object with the [`next_billing_date`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/ruby#next_billing_date) attribute. You can use this attribute to keep your database updated.